# Convert math expression to spoken words in python

Tags: python, latex, expression, data-conversion, spoken-language

I need to convert a mathematical expression into spoken words text, e.g "x^2" to "x to the power of 2" let's say, using python. For expression format, latex is a good but I do not succeed to convert latex format to text (**I need only text**, not voice - mp3). I found out about [sayTex](https://pypi.org/project/SayTeX/)  module in python but this are doing the opposite of what I need (convert spoken math into latex expression);

Are there some approaches that can I used to solve my problem?

I tried something with sympy but it failed:

```
from sympy import latex, sympify, pretty

def latex_to_text(latex_code):

    expr = sympify(latex_code, evaluate=False)

    text_representation = pretty(expr, use_unicode=True)

    return text_representation


latex_code = '\frac{1}{2} \times x^2'
human_readable_text = latex_to_text(latex_code)
print(human_readable_text)
```

Maybe the sympy is not the best tool for my problem

Comment: This would seem like a good use case for AI, otherwise this question might be off-topic due to looking for libraries/tools

Comment: as I said, there exists sayPay library that convert spoken math to latex code; so the back conversion (from latex to spoken math) I think should be easier..

Comment: You can always try to build one

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work, or atleast work for basic math expressions.

This library called [pylatexenc](https://pylatexenc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) will help you to convert latex to normal math text. This will help you to convert it to english words. You can try different things. Ont thing is that, you can use [Inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) with your custom word dict to convert expression to english text. This is a very basic approach

```py
import inflect

words = {
    "*": "times",
    "^": "raised to the power",
    "=": "equals",
    "+": "plus"
    # add more
}

def convert_math_expression(expression):
    p = inflect.engine()

    expression = expression.split()
    for i, e in enumerate(expression.copy()):
        if e in words:
            expression[i] = words[e]
        else:
            if not e.isalpha():
                expression[i] = p.number_to_words(e, andword=", and")
    return ' '.join(expression)

# put the converted math expression here
# needs spaces in between for split method to work
math_expression = "2 * x + 5 = 10"
english_text = convert_math_expression(math_expression)
print(english_text)
```

Output:

```
two times x plus five equals ten
```

Edit: previous answer using sympy won't work. here's the corrected one

Comment: Could you include the output of your code?

Comment: @Ayush Shah I don't think this works properly; I complain about that the expression is an equality, but even if I remove the equality sign,  ValidationError: 2 validation errors for NumberToWords
num
  instance of Number expected (type=type_error.arbitrary_type; expected_arbitrary_type=Number)
num
  str type expected (type=type_error.str)

Comment: @doog_math sorry, I just corrected the error. apologies for the incorrect answer before. It won't work with sympy, you you have to implement your own logic like I did above